# What affects how long it takes me to respawn?

Tags: spiral-knights

While playing lockdown, I've noticed that sometimes I respawn in 5 or so seconds, and sometimes it takes me upwards of 20.

Why is that?  Is it related to how well I'm doing?  It seems to go up when I die a lot.  Is it some kind of balancing?  How can I keep my respawn time low?

Comment: I believe that Lockdown tries to respawn players in waves - teamfortress 2 does something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is a rolling respawn queue](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Lockdown#Respawning).

This means that when the timer reaches 0 every knight waiting is respawned, and the counter is reset.